# Retrieve active logging levels of log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Anybody can suggest a way to retrieve all active levels in log4j during run time?

I tried to use:

```
LogLevel.getLog4JLevels()
```

and i got the following List:

```
[FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG]
```

but i want more specific information like orders between the levels.

for Example if my logging level is DEBUG and i want to change this level to the next level, 
i need to know which level is defined as the next level (from all active logging levels).

I wrote the following code:

```
public class Log4jLevelManager {

    private static ArrayList<Level> levels;
    private static Log4jLevelManager log4jLevelManager;

    private Log4jLevelManager(){    
        levels = new ArrayList<Level>();
        init();
    }
    public static Log4jLevelManager getInstance(){
        if (log4jLevelManager == null){
            log4jLevelManager = new Log4jLevelManager();
        }
        return log4jLevelManager;
    }

    public Level getNextLevel (Level level){

        int levelIndex = levels.indexOf( level );

        if (levelIndex == -1 || levelIndex + 1 == levels.size() ){
            return level;
        }else{
            return levels.get(levelIndex + 1);
        }

    }

    public Level getPrevLevel (Level level){

        int levelIndex = levels.indexOf( level );

        if (levelIndex == -1 || levelIndex == 0 ){
            return level;
        }else{
            return levels.get(levelIndex - 1);
        }
    }


    private static void init(){
        levels.add( Level.OFF );
        levels.add( Level.ALL );
        levels.add( Level.DEBUG );
        levels.add( Level.WARN ); 
        levels.add( Level.ERROR );
        levels.add( Level.FATAL );
        levels.add( Level.INFO ); 

        Collections.sort(levels, new Comparator<Level>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(Level level1, Level level2) {

                if (level1.isGreaterOrEqual( level2 ) & level2.isGreaterOrEqual( level1 ) ){
                    return 0;
                }

                if ( level1.isGreaterOrEqual( level2 ) ){
                    return 1;
                }
                return -1;
            }       
        });
    }           
}
```

The only disadvantage is that i need hard coded to add the loggers levels, any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Thanks,
Maxim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are ordered - the first is the most severe one, the last - is just printing debug info (the least important). See the source: http://bethecoder.com/open-source/log4j/log4j-1.2.16/org/apache/log4j/lf5/LogLevel.java.html

Comment: No one says that they are already ordered, you infer it from the code and not from the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LogLevel.encompasses()`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/lf5/LogLevel.html#encompasses%28org.apache.log4j.lf5.LogLevel%29) to detect the relationship between different levels. The items you got look like they are ordered by descending severity anyway - although I haven't found any clear guarantee to this in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you

```
public static Priority[] getAllPossiblePriorities()

Priority : 

    java.lang.Object
          extended by org.apache.log4j.Priority
```

which will Return all possible priorities as an array of Level objects in descending order.

Comment: This method is deprecated. see [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html). I am looking for a generic solution.